# Form doesn't run when I click button submit

Tags: codeigniter-2, codeigniter-form-helper

I am trying to create a form in CodeIgniter 2.1 but after creating it I push submit button and I don't obtain any kind of data.

Here is the code:

**View:**

```
<div id="logform"
    <?php 

        echo validation_errors();
        echo form_open('blog/validacion_registro');
        ?>     
    Direcci&oacute;n de correo <input type="text" id="ecorreo" name="correo" maxlength="30" /><br /><br />
            Usuario <input type="text" id="nusuario" name="usuario" maxlength="20" /><br /><br />
            Contrase&ntilde;a <input type="password" id="contrasena" name="contrasenya" maxlength="50" /><br /><br />
            Repetir contrase&ntilde;a <input type="password" id="rcontrasena" name="repcontrasenya" maxlength="50" /><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" id="entra" name="entrar" value="Entrar" />
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
class Blog extends CI_Controller 
{
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('anuncios/test');

}

    public function validacion_registro() //para validar los datos de registro de usuario
{
    //$this->load->library('form_validation');
    echo "Dentro de validacion_registro";
    $this->input->post('correo');
    $this->input->post('usuario');
    $this->input->post('contrasenya');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('correo','Direcci&oacute;n de correo','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('usuario','Nombre de usuario','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('contrasenya','Contrase&ntilde;a','required|md5');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('repcontrasenya','Confirmaci&oacute;n de contrase&ntilde;a','required|md5');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()===true)
     {
        redirect('anuncios/test');
        echo ("validaci&oacute;n v&aacute;lida");
     }
    else {
            $this->load->view('anuncios/test');
            echo ("validaci&oacute;n no v&aacute;lida");
         }  
}
?>
```

The view is in application/view folder and controller is in application/controller. 
Why I can't display any data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to close the form after the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" id="entra" name="entrar" value="Entrar" />
echo form_close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I typed echo form_close() as you told me but no data are displayed. What's wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, do you have a URL I could look at to troubleshoot?